# При запуске react проекта вылезает ошибка "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')" Где искать корни этого зла?

Tags: reactjs

Пытаюсь изучить react, на данном этапе возникла ошибка (полный текст)

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1108:24
    at updateMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22977:23)
    at Object.useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23553:20)
    at useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38475:25)
    at useCard (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1107:78)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:117:87)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22188:22)
    at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25070:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26782:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11780:18)
```

Никак не могу понять куда мне залезть, чтоб все исправить? Я не вижу конкретики, ни имени файла, ни номера строк, подскажите новичку пожалуйста!

Comment: Поскольку ошибка в файле `static/js/bundle.js` в строке 1108, позиции 24, можно предположить что проект уже собран (кем-то) и ты запускаешь уже сформированный проект (не в режиме разработчика)... Т.ч. повлиять (редактировать) такое не особо возможно. Работать нужно с "исходным кодом", там ошибка будет более детально расписана и там ее можно будет исправить. После этого собрать проект еще раз ииспользовать.

Comment: Вряд ли проект уже кем то собран, поскольку я с нуля создал папку frontend и уже по урокам недели две наполняю кодом и файлами

Comment: Тогда все еще более запутано... :) Поскольку совсем не ясно чего ты там накрутил.

Comment: Вот и я не знаю) Точнее не помню, перед выходными еще работал проект, под конец дня писал, писал, оно так сломалось, я решил, что в понедельник все верну на место, но потом уже после выходных совершенно забыл, что я там навернул)))

Comment: ищите где вы используете `filter`. Вы можете попробовать развернуть ошибку и возможно вам повезет и вы увидите источник (хотя бы дерево компонентов).